# Solving an equation for 3 unknowns

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

So I have the function $y=-a(x+b)^2+c$
And I also know that this equation goes through these three points 
$(0,0),\ (6,12),\ (2,8)$ 
I tried to make a system with $3$ equations from this info, but I was unable to solve it.

Comment: Which equation system do you find?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please show us the three equations you came up with, and your attempt at solving them.  Otherwise, you're just asking for someone to do your homework, which is not what this site is about.

Comment: If you want to see my scribbles all over pages to solve it ur welcome just ask for it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The system is given by
$$0=-a(0+b)^2+c$$
$$12=-a(6+b)^2+c$$
$$8=-a(2+b)^2+c$$
From the first equation we get $$c=ab^2$$ plugging this in equation (2) and (3) and solving for $$a$$ we get
$$\frac{8}{b^2-(2+b)^2}=a=\frac{12}{b^2-(6+b)^2}$$
Can you finish now?
Simplifying we get
$$2(12b+36)=3(4b+4)$$ This equation must be solved for $b$, it is linear in $$b$$

Comment: Yes i tried to solve those for finding the a b and c but i was unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Find quadratic polynomials $p(x)$, $q(x)$, $r(x)$ such that
\begin{align}\begin{cases}
p(6)=p(2)=0 ,\\
p(0)=1,
\end{cases}\qquad\begin{cases}
q(0)=q(6)=0 ,\\
q(2)=1,
\end{cases} \qquad\begin{cases}
r(2)=r(0)=0 ,\\
r(6)=1,
\end{cases} \end{align}
and take
$$y(x)=0\cdot p(x)+ 8\cdot q(x)+12 \cdot r(x).$$

Then $-b\:$ is the abscissa of the axis if symmetry of the resulting parabola.